# std::nothrow pretty much useless?

Tags: c++

> Nothrow constant: This constant value is used as an argument for
>   operator new and operator new[] to indicate that these functions shall
>   not throw an exception on failure, but return a null pointer instead.

But here in this simple example, instead of returning NULL, `new` throws exception:

```
struct SomeStruct
{
    SomeStruct() 
    {
        std::bad_alloc exception;
        throw exception;
    }
};

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
            SomeStruct* somestruct;
            somestruct = new (std::nothrow) SomeStruct; 
            return 0;
    }
```

Any explanation please? It simply indicates, despite having `(std::nothrow)` parameter to `new` we still need to put the code in `try...catch` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::nothrow` means that instead of `std::bad_alloc` being thrown on failure to acquire memory, the `new` expression returns `nullptr`. It does not mean that the `new` expression will not ever throw.

If your `SomeStruct` did not throw in its constructor, the `new` expression would never throw.

Comment: I am throwing 'std::bad_alloc' to simulate the same?

Comment: @Andrew: You throwing `std::bad_alloc` in a constructor has nothing to do with the implementation throwing `std::bad_alloc` because it was unable to allocate memory in which to construct your object.

Comment: @andrew, you are throwing bad_alloc, but not simulating the same. To see std::nothrow in action, see difference between `new(std::nothrow) char[ std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max() ]` and the same, without `std::nothrow`. nothrow refers to exceptions in acquiring available memory, not in what your constructor does.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is not thrown from `new` but from your `SomeStruct` c-tor.

`new` will throw an exception if memory can't be allocated. If you use the `std::nothrow` constant when memory can't be allocated, `new` will return `NULL`.

In that case, you should check for pointer `NULL` value before proceeding.

```
if (somestruct == NULL)
   // error 
else
   // continue
```